# Android App in Phone does not receive Data from WearApp when is closed

Tags: java, android, wear-os

Good morning,

I'm facing this problem. I developed an Android Wear App that sends messages to the Mobile App using the DataApi and PutDataRequest.

Everything works fine, and the mobile receives the messages and I can store them in a DataBase, etc.

The problem is that when the App in the phone is close, not in background, but completely closed, then it does not receive any messages. That means that all the info that I was sending from the Smartwatch to the Phone is lost.

Once I open the App in the Phone, all the data that was sent while the App was closed, is not syncronized anymore.

I would like to Open the mobile Phone from the Smartwatch, when it checks that is closed, so the info that it sends won't be lost. It is that possible to do??

Thanks!
Carlos

Comment: Have you use any service class that extends WearableListenerService?

Comment: I have it, yes. And I receive data in my phone, that works. The problem is when the App in the phone is completely closed, not even working in background. Then, my phone does not "opens" the App and the Data is lost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Service on your phone that extends [WearableListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService) and then declare it in your manifest as follows :

```
<service
        android:name=".MessageListener"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

You don't need to start this service, it will be started when a message, or a data change will be received.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have this already implemented in my app. I have a Service that extends from WearableListenerService, and therefore I can receive messages from the Wear. The problem is that I don't receive them IF the app is closed. The phone does not "open" my phone App, and then, I lose the data sended.

Comment: Yes, i understand what you mean, but normally, you don't need to open the app implementing the WearableListenerService for it to start when a message is received. Can you post some code from both side ? [Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DataLayer) is one of google sample i found useful.